# kube-state-metrics exports unexpected labels

Tags: prometheus

I've installed kube-state-metrics v2.3.0 on my k8s cluster (v1.20.7)

When I got the metrics kube_pod_* from kube-state-metrics, the metrics labels are different from the expected.

I expected below
[image: expected]

but I got

[image]

The label "pod" has the name of "kube-state-metrics" pod not the target pod.

The label "exported_pod" has the name of the target pod.

How can I change the label "exported_pod" to "pod"?

```
- job_name: kube-state-metrics-test
  honor_timestamps: true
  scrape_interval: 30s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: http
  follow_redirects: true
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [job]
    separator: ;
    regex: kube-state-(.*)
    target_label: __tmp_prometheus_job_name
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_label_app_kubernetes_io_instance, __meta_kubernetes_service_labelpresent_app_kubernetes_io_instance]
    separator: ;
    regex: (monitoring-state-metrics);true
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_label_app_kubernetes_io_name, __meta_kubernetes_service_labelpresent_app_kubernetes_io_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (kube-state-metrics);true
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: http
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_kind, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: Node;(.*)
    target_label: node
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_kind, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: Pod;(.*)
    target_label: pod
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: namespace
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: service
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: pod
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: container
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: job
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_label_app_kubernetes_io_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.+)
    target_label: job
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: endpoint
    replacement: http
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    modulus: 1
    target_label: __tmp_hash
    replacement: $1
    action: hashmod
  - source_labels: [__tmp_hash]
    separator: ;
    regex: "0"
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: endpoints
    kubeconfig_file: ""
    follow_redirects: true
    namespaces:
      names:
      - sre-mtr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long time. I got an answer.
If I set honor_labels true in the scrape_configs, which is located in the same depth of job_name,  I can get the pure metrics from the exporter.

https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config